# I2C address selection in PCA9685

Tags: i2c, addressing

I am using PCA9685 in a project. 3 are on the same i2c bus and thus I need to change the address of individual ICs. It has 5 selectable address bits as shown in the figure below:

[image: PCA]

The address will change depending on whether A0...A5 are tied to GND or VCC.

[Datasheet](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/PCA9685.pdf) says that:

> To conserve power, no internal pull-up resistors are incorporated on
>   the hardware selectable address pins and they must be pulled HIGH or
>   LOW.

Does it mean I need to use external resistors for pull up or pull down or am I allowed to directly connect the address pins to GND or VCC as per my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both. What they mean is that, if you connect the pin to either GND or VCC, there will be no current wasted due to some internal pull-up/pull-down.

But whether you connect it directly or through a resistor does not really matter. I suggest you connect them directly for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks dim. To save component cost and PCB space, I am going to tie the pins directly to VCC and GND.

Comment: That is what I'd do as well. I edited my post accordingly, by the way.

Comment: In a production design, your test engineer might prefer you connect through a resistor so the tester can override the pull-up/down and test the chips connectivity completely. In a hobby project, you don't need to worry about this.